# PostgreSql: how to create index for character varying array type column

Tags: postgresql

My table structure is like

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  seller_id integer,
  product_data  character varying[],
  ptype integer,
  CONSTRAINT config_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Index created: 
`CREATE INDEX product_name_idx ON Product USING gin (product_data);`

proudct_data column can have around 50 different product names at max in the array and the Product table has around 1M **UNIQUE** rows.
I need to find out seller_id s which have 'steel' as a product, where 'steel' may be a sub-string of the product name in product_data;

Currently I am using the following query:

```
 SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ptype in ( 2,3 ) and '%steel%' % any(product_data) offset 0 limit 10;
```

The above query gives the expected results, but as it is not using the `product_name_idx` index, its very slow. 
How can I create proper index on this column? Please help me out.

Comment: Have you tried it with only percent at the end? Because queries like `%xxx%` don't use indexes at all afaik.

Comment: Yes I tried that, but with no luck.

Comment: The `%` operator can not make use of an index. The list of operators that can use a GIN index are listed in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gin-builtin-opclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

I thought GIN indexes only work on tsvector data types?

Alter you product_data to a tsvector type, recreate the index and ensure you cast to tsvector on your query:

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ptype in ( 2,3 ) and '%steel%'::tsvector % any(product_data) offset 0 limit 10;
```

Comment: No, GIN indexes can also be used for arrays.

Comment: Do you have citation to hand?

Comment: The manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gin-builtin-opclasses.html

Comment: Oh ok, in which case this is misleading:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-indexes.html

Comment: Nowhere does it say that GIN indexes are **only** for full text search

Comment: Creates a GIN (Generalized Inverted Index)-based index. The column must be of tsvector type. Is what i was referring to. Hence my suggestion.

Comment: If i query using `product_data @@ to_tsquery('wire&steel')`, irrelevant results will come. For example, if one product in the product_data array is: 'steel' and another element in the same array is 'wire' then also this row will come in the result which I don't want. Only if product name contains wire and steel as a part of its name it should be listed. like if the product_data has 'wire of steel articles' it should match.